# Ubuntu with system on mdadm, broken grub, won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, raid, fstab, mdadm

My old disc started failing so I decided to change it. While moving data to a new disk, seeing how big it is, I though it would be a good decision to split the disk and add some insurance with RAID1 array. What can get wrong, right? Now it won't boot. I think I should have first moved the system, THEN add raid functionality. Doing both at the same time was a bad decision.

I did copied all the data, including hidden files. Then edited fstab, ran udate-initramfs, update-grub and grub-install

During the boot I get an error: Error 17: Cannot mount selected partition.
Then I can choose between kernel versions (Ubuntu 13.10 kernel 3.11.0-17...23) all giving the error.

I can not revert the process as the old disc is no longer working.

I am accessing the system through ubuntu installer - rescue mode - mount filesystem md127 (this rescue mode can detect and mount the raid partition without problems)

output of fdisk, blkid, fstab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgQ3B.jpg

mdadm config, detail and scan: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSAmt.jpg

Do you need any more data?

Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

I had it backwards, the /etc/fstab file you **should** use

```
/dev/md127 / ext3 errors=remount -ro 0 1
```

back to the way you had it.

I noticed your /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf doesn't exactly match the output of `sudo mdadm --detail --scan` and I wonder if that might be part of the issue. The entry /dev/md127 seems like it should be what it is but the output of `--detail --scan` is /dev/md/127_0.

Comment: Thank you. Then, I have a problem, that swap (sda2) is now showing in blkid, thus I don't know it's UUID. Why won't a partition show in blkid?

Comment: @David162795 leave that commented out for now by placing a # in front of that line in /etc/fstab. boot up with no swap and you can then create a swap partition after you get booted back into the system.

Comment: @David162795 I included a link to how to build a swap, use gparted to partition a swapspace before you begin 2-4GB.

Comment: Following your advice, I did rewritten fstab to use UUID=209808fa-... and '#' commented out the swap, however the problem persists without any changes.